# regex to match this repeating pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was able to match the string `[ORG] someText` with this regex: `/^\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]+$/`

```js
var selectedText = "[ORG] dd";

if (selectedText.match(/^\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]+$/)) {
    console.log("working");
}
```

The input text could have anything in the tag followed by any word.

---

Now I have the text as: `[ORG] Lorem [ORG] ipsum` (ending with a space)

I tried to match this by grouping the pattern and repeating it with a `+` (one or more occurances).

This way: `/^(\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]\s)+$/`

However it doesnt match.

**Basically, it should match:**

```
[tag] sometext

[tag] sometext [tag2] someOtherText // ending with or without a space
```

So, in general, it needs to match a pattern of `a tag followed by a space and a word`.

**What it shouldnt match:**

```
[tag] sometext someMoreText

[tag] sometext someMoreText [tag9]

[tag] [tag9] sometext someMoreText
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't simply use the global flag `/\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]+$/g`?

Comment: Then one has to remove anchors, but that's a good point anyway.

Comment: @Tomalak I couldnt get it working. :( http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/27vfd38w/4/

Comment: On a different note, `[^\W_]` is better written as `[A-Za-z0-9]` (`[A-Z0-9]` with the `i` flag) - try to avoid double negations in regex just to make the expression shorter. Think of the people who maintain that code. Regex are hard enough to read without these "clever" constructs.

Comment: @RahulDesai That's not how you do global matching in JavaScript. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/27vfd38w/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
/^(\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]+(?:\s|$))+$/
```

... that is, adding an alternation between a whitespace and the end-of-line boundary (for the last pattern in the string doesn't end with a whitespace).

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tI2aK6/2). Also note that if you only need to check whether or not a string matches that pattern, `String#match` method is actually an overkill; instead you should `RegExp#text`:

```
var tagsPattern = /^(\[(ORG|PER|LOC)]\s[^\W_]+(\s|$))+$/;
if (tagsPattern.test(str)) {
  // matches 
}
```